# Can't change background colour of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I can't change the colour of the background that my navigation bar has. I'm not using any framework so there's no conflicts. Here's the code that I have tried:

```css
.navigation-right {
  float: right;
}
.navigation-left {
  float: left;
}
.navigation-main {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
.navigation-main li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navigation-main a {
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="navigation">
    <nav class="navigation-main">
      <ul>
        <div class="navigation-right">
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation-left">
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

Comment: Note: your markup is not valid, only `li` can be a direct child of `ul/ol`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an **overflow:hidden** in the parent of the floating elements. Without it, the browser can't calculate the height hence the background colour not coming through. Try adding this line to your CSS:

```
.navigation-main{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; // Add this
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you have fixed my problem. :D

Comment: Glad to help! A vote would be highly appreciated ;-)

Comment: @Teknotica +1 , even though I knew that height was the issue I didn't know that `overflow:hidden;` can solve the problem, but `overflow:hidden` makes sure that the child elements don't extend more than the height of parent element; Here we haven't specified any height so shouldn't the browser throw in some err or just assume the height to be zero??

Comment: Even though this works, that's *not* the best way to clear floats!

Comment: This is a very known way of clearing floats. I never said it was the "best" but I personally use it all the time without any issues. A good article over here that explains different ways of clearing floats http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: It is a *known* way indeed, but not in all cases the best way. In this case, I would never use it because menus are tricky. As soon as you may come up with submenus and the bunch, you'll probably get scrollbar issues. Note that the article that you point to is very, very old - must 've been there before I entered SO I believe! A more comprehensive article can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Comment: @Teknotica don't know ?

Comment: I would use it indeed. It's up to people to decide.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *clear your floats*. Using `overflow` is a sneaky, though not always preferable way. The best way - in my opinion - is using a pseudo element, like so:

```css
/* Clear */
ul::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.navigation-right {
  float: right;
}
.navigation-left {
  float: left;
}
.navigation-main {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
.navigation-main li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navigation-main a {
  color: #F2F2F2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="navigation">
    <nav class="navigation-main">
      <ul>
        <div class="navigation-right">
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation-left">
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Menu</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

Note though, that you oughtn't split up your menu like that, with divs inside a list. Instead, create two seperate lists.

Answer (score 1):

Just corrected your HTML and add overflow:hidden to you're `.navigation-main{...}`
[JsFiddle There](http://jsfiddle.net/eund0tak/1/)

Teknotica had it aswell :)